# Angular Azure AD - MsalModule. Get the Access Token after authentication

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory

I just install MsalModule and followed the steps in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular.

In my app.module.ts, I specified the MsalModule in the import section as followed

```
   MsalModule.forRoot({ 
      clientID: myClientId, 
      authority: myAuthority,
      redirectUri: myReDirectUri,
      validateAuthority: true,
      cacheLocation: 'localstorage',
      postLogoutRedirectUri: myPostLogoutRedirectUri,

      popUp: false,   
      level: LogLevel.Verbose,
      piiLoggingEnabled: true,
    })
```

I also add the broadcast as followed

```
this.loginSuccessSubscription = this.broadCastService.subscribe("msal:loginSuccess", (payload) => {

  alert("Login Success");
});

 this.loginTokenSuccessSubscription = this.broadCastService.subscribe("msal:loginTokenSuccess", (payload) => {


  alert("Acquired Token");
 })
```

After successfully authenticating to Azure, it  redirect back to the web client. I hit F12 and see the id token but not the access token.  I verified this by clicking F12, Network, Headers and don't see the access token.

Visual Studio Code breaks on  broadcast successful login but never on aquired token.

How do I specified MsalServer to return the access  token after authentication?

Thanks.

Comment: This is because you didn't specific any resources you want to call. You can use `consentScopes` to specific resources with scopes which you want to call to obtain the access token to call the it.

Comment: In the document it points out that: `consentScopes` : Allows the client to express the desired scopes that should be consented. Scopes can be from multiple resources/endpoints. **Passing scope here will only consent it and no access token will be acquired till the time client actually calls the API. This is optional if you are using MSAL for only login(Authentication).**